# Is it possible to lock a database table record indefinitely via JDBC/hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, locking

I am working on a Java web application which involves allocating certain resource to each user.

The resource is assigned by the server to a user when he/she logs on, and reclaimed when user logs off/session times out.

There are multiple server instances running the web, and the same resource cannot be shared between them at the same time. So once the resource is allocated to a user, it is exclusive for that user until the server reclaims it or stops running. As a result, the server end has to be able to check the availability of the resource and release it if it has crushed (otherwise the resource cannot be reallocated via other server instances).

My plan is to have the resource definitions stored in a database table with each record representing one such resource, and have each server reading and locking a record from it once the resource has been assigned to a user, so that no other server instances can allocate it again while it is in use, and server malfunction would release the lock and make the resource available.

The problem is that this record level lock has to **remain active indefinitely**, i.e. as long as the user stays online the lock will be there to notify other server that the resource has been allocated already.

So I am wondering if it is possible to apply such kind of lock with either JDBC or hibernate? If not possible, is there any alternative that can achieve the same effect without locking?

Comment: Table and/or row locking depends on database engine, not on JDBC. JDBC can do it as well depending on the transaction level you set for your connection.

Comment: Sounds like a bad design that won't scale to me.

Comment: @duffymo Scalability is not a concern here. This web application is for internal use and the total number of users does not exceeds a few hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

No, a database lock is not intended for this kind of usage. A lock is part of a transaction and transactions should be short.

You can manage the state of a resource with an extra table "resource usage". It can have a column related to the resource definition ID, an "in use" flag, the user ID, the server ID and the last time the resource was used.

A server can claim a resource for a user by inserting or updating a row in the "resource usage" table and setting the "in use" flag to true (this needs to be done within one short transaction). If two servers / transactions claim the same resource, one transaction will fail (or the update will result in 0 rows updated). Catch this failure and repeat the actions for another unclaimed resource.

When a server starts, it needs to check for any claimed resources and unclaim them (e.g. in case a server was killed and started again). If a server crashes, another server will have to unclaim the resources claimed by the crashed server. This implies that servers are somehow aware of each others health (online / offline). One method is to have a separate table with "resource servers" in which each server regularly updates a timestamp in a row specific for the server: if the timestamp is not updated for a while, another healthy server can decide to unclaim the resources from the server that has gone offline. Mind you: this is tricky to get right (e.g. if the database was offline for a while, the servers must wait an extra while after the database is back online again before looking for offline servers). Maybe you can find an alternative for the "resource servers" table which uses some sort of clustering technology that solves this for you.

Finally, a sweeper service within each server needs to watch the "last used" timestamps for "in use" resources. The sweeper service should have nothing to report, but if sessions go missing or cleanup code is not properly functioning, the sweeper service will at least inform you that there is a resource leak.